# chrome update version 99.0.4844.84 does not allow insecure content from localhost

Tags: google-chrome, http, localhost

Since chrome update version 99.0.4844.84 I am unable to load http (unsecure) resources from localhost.

This setting chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost DOES NOT WORK

I have uninstalled chrome and reinstalled it yet issue persists.

Firefox does allow insecure content from local host so I can continue to use this for dev.

Generating a SSL certificate for localhost is not a viable option.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and been able to implement a fix?